# How to print the string a pointer points to while debugging using GDB?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gdb

How do I inspect a string a pointer is pointing to when stepping through a program using GDB?

I can see the a pointer is pointing to `0x82c6e10`. I know it is a string. How do I print it?

Using `printf("%s\n", 0x82c6e10)` gives `Bad format string, missing '"'.` The fact that gdb does not complain of unknown command tells me that the solution is some variation of what I am doing. Am I right? I tried escaping the quotes but that did not help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here `printf` is not a function, but a `gdb` command.  Omit the parentheses.

Better yet, just use the `print` command, or the `x` command with format `/s`

(You can actually call the C function `printf()` with the `call` command.)`

`gdb` has voluminous help available with the `help` command.  Try it.

Answer (score 21):

Use `x` rather than `p`:

```
x /s 0x82c6e10
```

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
print (char *)pointer
```

Answer (score 3):

print (char*)0x82c6e10